# how to stop the redirection of login lightbox, if username password is wrong?

Tags: javascript, php, html

lightbox

```
<div class="modalBody">          
 <form method="post" action="login.php">
<table>
<tr>   
<td>User Name*</td>
<td>
<input name="fname" type="text" class="input" value="" /></td>  </tr>
<tr>  <td>Password</td>
 <td>
  <input name="password" type="password" class="input" /> </td>  </tr>

<td>Not registered yet, <a href="registration.php" style="color:#FFFFFF">Click here</a></td>
</tr>  
<tr height="25">    <td  colspan="2" align="center"> 
<input type="image" name="BtnSubmit" id="BtnSubmit" src="images/login-button.png" alt="Submit" onClick="javascript:return onSub();" style="border-width:0px;" /></a></td> </tr>

               <span style="color:#FF0000" >
 <?php  if(isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && $_REQUEST['msg'] == 'wrong')
echo ' Please Enter Username & Password!!!!!!';
elseif(isset($_REQUEST['msg']) && $_REQUEST['msg'] == 'incorect1')
echo ' Username Or Password Is Incorrect!!!!!';
?>      </span></table>
</form>      </div>
```

javascript:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function revealModal(divID)
{
  window.onscroll = function () { document.getElementById(divID).style.top = document.body.scrollTop; };
  document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById(divID).style.top = document.body.scrollTop;
}

function hideModal(divID)
{
  document.getElementById(divID).style.display = "none";
}
  </script>
```

The thing is that if i m submitting with wrong user name & password, the page is redirecting to the header location page only changing the header location like this & the lightbox got disappeared

```
header('Location:'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']."?msg=wrong");
```

But i dont want to redirect to any page after submission if there is wrong user name or password or the fields are blank, i want to stay in that modal box with the error msg.. Any help ?? Thanks ..

Answer (score 0):

First of all; you cannot change headers once HTML has been printed out. So for you to be able to set the header, you must first redirect to a new page - or reload it entirely.

However; it sounds to me like you're in need of AJAX.

When the user submits the form, a call to an AJAX function is made - which in turn, talks with another PHP file, handling the verification for the login.

If the login was successful, you will want to start the session for the user and reload the page using Javascript's: `window.location.href`. If the login was unsuccessful, you will want to manipulate the HTML of a given "error element" so to speak -- Or simply show an element as simple as:

`<div class='formError'>Wrong Username/Password combination`